# scrapy running 2 spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I run 2 spiders in series? Running this runs the first spider but not the second. Is there a way to wait for one to finish?:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider1".split())

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider2".split())
```

Edit1: I changed it using .wait() to:

```
spider1 = subprocess.Popen(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider1".split()))
spider1.wait()

spider2 = subprocess.Popen(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider2".split()))
spider2.wait()
```

Did I do it wrong because it will just runs the first one

Edit2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.6', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 109, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 109, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named settings
1
```

Comment: Do you want them to run at the same time, or the second one have to run when the first have finished?

Comment: second one run when the first finishes.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Subprocess, which has a [.wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) function. Or you could use `.call()` in subprocess, which automatically waits and print it to get the terminal text from calling the `scrapy crawl`.

```
spider1 = subprocess.call(["scrapy", "crawl", "spider1"])
print spider1

spider2 = subprocess.call(["scrapy", "crawl", "spider2"])
print spider2
```

This method will automatically wait until the first spider is done and then call the seconds spider

Comment: .call just draws a bunch of errors so I went with .wait() but I think I did it wrong. I edited the question.

Comment: @user3831011look at my answers example, you no longer need cmdline.exectue(). Just look at my example and try like that

Comment: @user3831011 please look at the answer now, this should be what you are looking for

Comment: Exactly as you put creates errors thats why I was gonna use the .wait() function, but I added the traceback to edit2

Comment: Are you running this in the same directory as your spiders?

Comment: nope, but I just tried same directory and same error.